# Remove part of a string from a variable in bash containing a forward slash

Tags: bash, testing, split, printf, echo

I have an array of strings I want to print for a bash script that tests my C programs. The arrays contents are like this:

```
PASSED TESTS: (4)

✓ tests/test_sample_one.in
✓ tests/test_sample_two.in
✓ tests/test_sample_three.in
✓ tests/test_sample_four.in
```

I however want to print it out like this:

```
PASSED TESTS: (4)

✓ test_sample_one
✓ test_sample_two
✓ test_sample_three
✓ test_sample_four
```

Here is the part of the code I've written for printing out the results. I think this is all that is relevant but I can post further code upon request.

I have successfully used the line `i=${i%.*}` to remove the `.in` on the end but the line `i=${i#*/ }` doesn't seem to work at removing the characters before the `/`.

```
printf "PASSED TESTS: ($passed_tests)\n\n"
for i in "${passed_tests_arr[@]}"
do
    printf "✓ "
    i=${i%.*}
    i=${i#*/ }
    echo "$i"
done
```

Comment: you got blank in you script, remove the blank will do the job ${i#*/}

Comment: @sigmalha that worked. What would be the appropriate course of action on stackover flow for this question. Would it be better to delete the question or answer the question with advice on why it would work now that the syntax is correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code is correct except for a blank in the script in line 6.

```
printf "PASSED TESTS: ($passed_tests)\n\n"
for i in "${passed_tests_arr[@]}"
do
    printf "✓ "
    i=${i%.*}
    i=${i#*/ }
    echo "$i"
done
```

Without the blank the code is:

```
printf "PASSED TESTS: ($passed_tests)\n\n"
for i in "${passed_tests_arr[@]}"
do
    printf "✓ "
    i=${i%.*}
    i=${i#*/}
    echo "$i"
done
```

This code can then print the correct output:

```
PASSED TESTS: (4)

✓ test_sample_one
✓ test_sample_two
✓ test_sample_three
✓ test_sample_four
```

Answer (score 0):

You have an additional space.
You can make the loop a little shorter with

```
printf "PASSED TESTS: ($passed_tests)\n\n"
for i in "${passed_tests_arr[@]}"
do
    # Not needed: printf "✓ "
    i=${i%.*}
    # Not needed: i=${i#*/ }
    echo "${i/ *\// }"
done
```

Comment: It doesn't appear as if the ✓ gets printed in this?

Comment: I thought the ✓ was part of your input lines. Otherwise a simple replacement seems better.

Comment: could the last line then be replaced with `echo "✓ ${i/ *\// }"`

Comment: That is possible, but I would go for echo "✓ ${i#*/}"